# serialise array will inputs of same name

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, serialization, post

i've got 3 inputs, 2 of which i want in the same array (name="notes['a']" and name="notes['b']")  but when i use jquerys' serializeArray() it puts them all at the same 'level'. But i want to use php to serialise the posted notes array into the database using the method thats been working for inputs that aren't part of an array (ie name="basic"

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $var => $value) {

    if(!strstr(strtolower($value['name']),'added')) $q1 .= "".$value['name']."='".$value['value']."',";

}

echo $q = "UPDATE ".$_POST['table']." SET ".rtrim($q1,',')." WHERE ".$_POST['idField']."=".$_POST['id']." ";    


*the array $_POST['data'] is getting posted as;*
 [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => notes[\'a\']
                    [value] => dan@jynk.net
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => notes[\'b\']
                    [value] => Daniel Crabbe
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => test
                    [value] => Daniel Crabbe
                )

        )
```

but i guess it should be along these lines?

```
[data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array{
                Array(
                    [name] => notes[\'a\']
                    [value] => dan@jynk.net
                )
                Array
                (
                    [name] => notes[\'b\']
                    [value] => Daniel Crabbe
                )
            )


            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => test
                    [value] => Daniel Crabbe
                )

        )
```

how can i get jquery to respect the arrays in the input array? any help welcome...

**UPdates**
no got it like this but want everything on level [0] for easy access...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => cm_email_to
            [value] => dan@jynk.net
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => cm_name_to
            [value] => Daniel Crabbe
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => cm_moveToList
            [value] => 
        )

)

*inputs*
<input id="cm_email_to" name="cm_email_to" value="dan@jynk.net" class="toPostCM" />
<input id="cm_name_to" name="cm_name_to" value="Daniel Crabbe" class="toPostCM" />

*jquery*
var dataCMSettings = $(".toPostCM").serializeArray();
```

Comment: `UPDATE ".$_POST['table']."`: don't forget to **escape** any data you put in a SQL query, or you'll be vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok - this does exactly what i need...

```
var params = {};

$('.toPostCM').each(function(index,value) {
    params[value.name] = value.value;
});

console.log(params);

*gives me*
Array
(
    [cm_email_to] => dan@jynk.net
    [cm_name_to] => Daniel Crabbe
    [cm_moveToList] => 
)
```

thanks all...

Answer (score 3):

Try taking the array indicies out of the input name:

```
<input name="notes[]" value="val1" />
<input name="notes[]" value="val2" />
```

Comment: need the names and values. removed the notes[] completely now but adds each field as and another object, ie [1], [2] etc.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from your array indices in your HTML, so `array['a']` becomes `array[a]`.

Comment: thanks - tried that but keeps in putting every field as a seperate array entry whereas i need everything at [0]...